# How can I learn biology by myself?

Tags: human-biology, species-identification, cell-biology, botany, zoology

I am only 15 years old,and my primary school education hasn't been that good,also I forgot a lot of things. I would like to start again,and I am asking for your advice. What are some of the good websites/books/methods that can help me?

Comment: I'd look into MOOCs on a site like [edX](https://www.edx.org/course/subject/biology-life-sciences). These courses are recorded by talented and engaging professors and are often available for free (at edX you only need to pay to get a certificate of completion, not to take the course)

Comment: There is a game on google where you type 2-3 unlikely words like " silver microbiology horn" and " indigo evolution chemical" and "photosynthesis cell jogging" see what information arises. Wikipedia is good for the main biology course: mitochondria, microbiology, photosynthesis, gametes, recessive, inheritance, all that kind of thing.Read what you are interested in, cell biology, zoology, biomimetics, nature magazine,  paleobiology...

Comment: Khan Academy...